# What does __hash__ on a Python file object do?

Tags: python

I noticed that file objects are hashable and can be used for keys in a Python dictionary, but I can't seem to figure out how a file object is hashed.  Does this just use the inode or something similar depending on OS?

I've tried to look in the Python 2.7.6 source, but came up empty.  It looks like Objects/fileobject.c has NULL for the tp_hash function pointer.  So, I'm guessing there some default hash function that the file object is piggy-backing on.  Any idea how this works?

Side note, I'm assuming that since file objects are hashable it's ok to use them as a dict key.  Any downsides to this that I'm not seeing?

Here's an example proving the 'hashability':

```
In [1]: x = open('test.txt', 'r')

In [2]: x.__hash__
Out[2]: <method-wrapper '__hash__' of file object at 0x105760f60>

In [4]: hash(x)
Out[4]: 274161910
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are hashed by object id, not by any features of the on-disk file itself.  Each file object has its own hash, even if they are referencing the same file:

```
>>> f1 = open('someFile', 'r')
>>> f2 = open('someFile', 'r')
>>> hash(f1)
8702521
>>> hash(f2)
8702539
```

You can use a file object as a dict key, but be aware of this object-based hashing.  The hash is unique to the file *object*, not the actual file or its contents.

That said, it's a little hard to think of use cases for using a file object as a dict key.  If the file is open, keeping the object around as a dict key will leave the file open, which may prevent other programs from using it, etc.  In general with file objects you want to get your data out and close the file as soon as is practical, because files are external resources and you want to release them as soon as you can.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  So, follow up question.  Why don't lists 'hash' like this, by object id?  I'm not saying it's a good idea, but then you could use a list as a key in a dict.  I know a list is mutable, but isn't a file object as well?  Just trying to understand the reasoning on when an object is deemed hashable by object id vs not hashable at all even though every object has an id.

Comment: @durden2.0: A file object is mutable, but mutating it does not affect its hash.  If lists were hashed by id, then equal but distinct list objects wouldn't hash equally.  So if you did `x = [1, 2, 3]; d[x] = 1`, and then tried to access `d[[1, 2, 3]]`, it wouldn't find it, because the two `[1, 2, 3]` are different objects (even though they have the same contents).  This isn't what you want with lists.  There are other questions on SO about this.  If you have more questions about hashing by object id in general you should ask that separately, since it's a bit off the topic of this question.

Comment: @durden2.0: there is no way you can make a file object not be equal to itself; the equality test is stable (only true for identical objects). Thus the hash remains stable too.

Answer (score 4):

`__hash__` is inherited from `object` and is based entirely on the `id()` value of the object (e.g. the memory address in CPython).

That's because two `file` objects are only equal if they are identical, e.g. if they are in fact the same object.

There is no custom equality test for file objects; such equality would have to take into account the filename, the mode, the buffer states and the current file pointer, if that were ever implemented. With no equality test, there is no point in implementing a hash function either.